# How can I add a label name in bottomNavItem in Flutter using specific model class?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image]
[image]

Please help to add navbar icon label

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          currentIndex: _currentindex,
          showUnselectedLabels: true,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          selectedItemColor: kPrimaryColor,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
                label: "Home",
                icon: Image.asset(
                  "assets/icons/home.png",
                  height: 24,
                  width: 24,
                  color: Color(0xFF050C1F).withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
                //SvgPicture.asset(Assets.icons.homeIcon),
                activeIcon: Image.asset(
                  "assets/icons/home.png",
                  height: 24,
                  width: 24,
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                ) /*SvgPicture.asset(
                  Assets.icons.homeIcon,
                )*/
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: "Sponsors",
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(Assets.icons.sponsorsIcon),
              activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
                Assets.icons.sponsorsIcon,
                color: kPrimaryColor,
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "Messages",
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(Assets.icons.mail),
                activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  Assets.icons.mail,
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                )),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "More",
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(Assets.icons.moreIcon),
                activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  Assets.icons.moreIcon,
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                )),
          ],
          onTap: (index) {

            jwt != null ?
            setState(() {
              _currentindex = index;
            }) : Get.to(() => LoginScreen(),
                transition:
                sendTransition);
          },
        ),
        body: pages[_currentindex]);
  }

_bottomNavigationBarItem({Widget? icon, String? label}) {
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: icon!,
      ),
      label: label,
    );
  }
```

please try to provide more detail on what you want to achieve & how much you try